# Он предлагал ей все деньги мира – лишь бы она продала ему картину.

Tags: синтаксис

*Он предлагал ей все деньги мира – **лишь бы она продала ему картину**.*

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно считать выделенный фрагмент целевым придаточным? (*предлагал с какой целью? - чтобы продала*) или это самостоятельное предложение, выражающее желание?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это придаточное цели, для связи вместо обычного союза ЧТОБЫ используется **союз-частица ЛИШЬ БЫ**.  Такие СПП считаются **специализированными** по тематике.

Частица ЛИШЬ БЫ вносит в предложение компонент **особой желательности**, а в главной части присутствует **особая лексика** (способен, согласен на всё), выражающая высокую готовность субъекта к действию (предлагал **все** деньги мира).